# Remover caractere de um valor gerado

Tags: javascript

Tem como pegar um valor gerado, checar quantos caracteres tem e remover caso necessário?
Exemplo: Se o valor for de apenas 4 caracteres (ex: 1844) ele ignora, porém se passar de 4 caracteres uma função remove os caracteres para ficar apenas 4, tipo se tiver 6 caracteres (ex: 184455) remove 2 para ficar apenas 4 novamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim

```js
function remove_chars(num) {
  var str_num = String(num);
  if(str_num.length > 4) {
    var removals = str_num.length - 4;
    str_num = str_num.slice(0, -removals);
  }
  if(isNaN) {
       return str_num;
  }
  return parseInt(str_num);
}
console.log(remove_chars(325325));
```

Nota: Se tiver a certeza que são sempre números, pode retirar `if(isNaN) {return str_num;}`

Answer (score 3):

Use o método [substring(start,end)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

O método possui dois parâmetros para definir o que será extraído:

- O **primeiro parâmetro** você define o índice inicial que você quer - *no exemplo começo do primeiro char (0)*.
- O **segundo parâmetro** você define quantos caracteres deseja extrair - *no exemplo quero apenas os primeiros 4 após a posição zero*.

Veja o exemplo que irá remover os caracteres excedentes ao sair do input (evento blur).

```js
var $meuTxt = document.getElementById('meuTxt');
$meuTxt.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  var valor = this.value;
  this.value = valor.substring(0, 4);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="meuTxt" />
```